# Usage and meaning of 連絡を入れる

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage, nuances

Is this true?

> 連絡{れんらく}を入{い}れる = 連絡する

In what situations is it used, and how is it used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's true.　You can use 連絡を入れる in the same way as 連絡する but I feel it is a little literary.

Comment: when used 入れる is more formal, too? I can use it with other suru-verbs?

Comment: I don't think 連絡を入れる is more formal. I think up only one example like 電話する=電話を入れる.

Comment: a good translation could be "to put in contact..."?

Comment: Yes,but I'm not sure because my English level isn't high.

Answer (score 4):

連絡を入れる emphasizes the act of delivering a message; it's something more than just "communicate."